# Seed a new SVN repository with a revision number

Tags: svn

I am thinking about creating a new repository in SVN for a section of our main project. I would like to respect the revision number we have got to, though.

So my question is: Is it possible, when creating a new SVN repository to "seed" the revision number to, say 1100?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the section in the SVN book titled [Filtering Repository History](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering). It shows how you can extract part of repository A (including all history) and put it in its own repository B.

By default the svndumpfilter command will keep the revision numbers, though it has options to control that.

Comment: That looks like the way to do it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Can I advise not to do that?  If it's a section of your main project, put it in the same repository.  If you think you need to synchronise revision numbers, remember that you're going to get out of sync again very quickly and that you're going to have two repository with identical but probably-unrelated commits.

Comment: You can absolutely recommend not to do that. I know it's positively mucky. I'm wanting to "promote" a solution to its own repository, instead of our repository having many solutions. It's probably as a product of me not configuring SVN correctly in the first place, but hindsight and all that ...